# urc_id_SEQ.nextval gives invalid identifier error?

Tags: oracle11g

I have created a sequence but it gives me invalid identifier error. I am running  select urc_id_SEQ.nextval from dual;

Comment: What DDL did you use to create the sequence? Are you running the query as the same user that owns the sequence?

Comment: yes. I have connected to schema A, then create the sequence on schema A. I am also running the sequence on schema A only.

Comment: What DDL did you use to create the sequence?

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE  "A"."urc_id_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the sequence *without* using double quotes in the command. If you use double-quotes it makes the name case sensitive and then you must *always* use double quotes to reference the object. Eliminating the quotes keeps the object name case-insensitive.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE A.urc_id_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE ORDER NOCYCLE;
```